# Admin Posts List (edit.php) by post IDs

Tags: plugin-development, query, wp-list-table

I'm writing a plugin that creates posts in bulk. I provide a way for the user to set certain parameters of the created posts beforehand. But it would be useful to use the WordPress default "All Posts" (`edit.php`) interface to fine-tune the details after the posts are created. I had a look at the `class-wp-list-table.php` and duplicating its functionality is going to be a lot of work.

The best solution would be to just send the user to edit.php - limited only to the posts created by my plugin. I have the IDs of the posts, so I'm looking for a solution like `edit.php?id=1&id=2`, revealing a nice list table with only the posts with those IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

It is important to prefix all your variable names, `id` seems not be in the [reserved terms list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms), but anyway this practice avoids any unforeseen bug.

```
/**
 * Usage:
 * http://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?my_pids=4088,4090,4092,4094
 */
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'limit_post_list_wpse_96418' );

function limit_post_list_wpse_96418( $query ) 
{
    // Don't run on frontend
    if( !is_admin() )
        return $query;

    global $pagenow;

    // Restrict to Edit page
    if( 'edit.php' !== $pagenow )
        return $query;

    // Check for our filter
    if( !isset( $_GET['my_pids'] ) )
        return $query;

    // Finally, filter
    $limit_posts = explode( ',', $_GET['my_pids'] ); // Convert comma delimited to array    
    $query->set( 'post__in', $limit_posts );      

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Great! Took a couple of weeks, but finally at this stage. Thanks for the answer.